# Url for API to login and get access token

Tags: laravel-5

I want to validate the email and password of someone connecting through an API.

The idea is that they login through POST to site.com/api/v1/token?email=foo@bar.com&password=foobar

I was reading that best practices should be to make a https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests to handle the validation, but I couldn't understand how to validate the $user, because when I created the new Class there wasn't any request there.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something.
I was able to do it through the Controller just checking if the user exists and the password is valid.

The app would ping this URL with email/password, then get a Token as a response with the $user information and use this token to post/edit/delete other data

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a FormRequest class by using artisan command:

`php artisan make:request ApiLoginRequest`

After artisan command, it will create a new file inside you `app/Http/Request` with name `ApiLoginRequest.php`.

Inside this file you have to define validation rules like this.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiLoginRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
        
        return $rules;
    }
    
    /**
     * @name messages
     * 
     * @description 
     */
    public function messages() {
        return [
            'email.required' => 'Required',
            'password.required' => 'Required',
            'email.email' => 'Must be a valid email address',
            'email.exists' => 'Email address not found'
            
        ];
    }
}
```

Then after you have to use this Request class inside your controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Request\ApiLoginRequest;

class ApiLoginController extends Controller {

    public function login ( ApiLoginRequest $request ){
        $user = \App\User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->find();
        if( \Hash::check( $user>password, $request->password ) ){
            // Do Login processed
        }else{
            $data = [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Password dows not match'
            ];
            return response()->json( $data, 500);
        }
    }

}
```

Like this you can use FormRequest class and benefit of this FormRequest class you can reuse this validation rules and also your controller looks good.

Comment: Since this is an API, i ended up  using Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $request->input('password')])